# What is the proper approach to read back data from a json file in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have a .json data file located on my local disk. It's in the following format:

```
{
"employees" [
{
"Name" : "John",
"Location" : "Austin",
"Age" : "30"
},
.....
],
.....
}
```

Now I want to read the file and load the data into a UITableView. My initial thought is to put the data into an array and use the array to populate the table. But I can't find the right steps to realize this.

The methods I have tried so far:

```
        let currentFileURL = URL(string: currentFileString)
        do {
            let currentData = try Data(contentsOf: currentFileURL!)

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: currentData, options:.allowFragments)

        //***********************************************************
        //How to proceed here? Or am I using the right methods above? 
        //***********************************************************              

            } catch {
             //catch the error here
            }
```

Thank you for your help!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create custom `class` or `struct` and use Array of that custom class object with you `tableView` methods.

```
class Employee {

    var name: String?
    var location: String?
    var age: Int?

    init?(dictionary: [String: String]) }
        if let name = employee["Name"], let location = employee["Location"], let ageStr = employee["Age"], let age = Int(ageStr) {
            self.name = name
            self.location = location 
            self.age = age
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now declare one Array of `Employee` instance in your Controller and use that array with your `tableView` methods.

```
var employees = [Employee]()

//Initialize array 
do {
   let currentData = try Data(contentsOf: currentFileURL!)
   if let jsonArray = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: currentData, options: [])) as? [[String: String]] {
       self.emplyees = jsonArray.flatMap({ Employee(dictionary: $0) })
   }
   //Reload the tableView
   self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Now simply use this Array with your `UITableView` methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.employees.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell") as! CustomTableCell
    cell.lblName = self.employees[indexPath.row].name
    //set other details

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let employees = jsonData["employees"] as? [[String:String]] {
    for employee in employees {

        if let name = employee["Name"] {
            // Set employee name
        }

        if let location = employee["Location"] {
            // Set employee location
        }

        if let age = employee["Age"] {
            // Set employee age
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a struct `Employee` and a data source array

```
struct Employee {
    var title : String
    var location : String
    var age : String
}

var employees = [Employee]()
```

then parse the JSON.

**Important:** You must use `fileURLWithPath` on `URL` when accessing a file system URL.

```
let currentFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentFileString)
do {
    let currentData = try Data(contentsOf: currentFileURL)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:currentData, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    let people = json["employees"] as! [[String:String]]
    for person in people {
        employees.append(Employee(title: person["Name"]!, location: person["Location"]!, age: person["Age"]!))
    }    
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Since the json file is on local disk and you are responsible for the content the forced unwrapping is safe or reveals a design error.